# Save record and showing in table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I try to add a save button and it gives me this error in Eclipse console

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1698)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1617)
    at LOTest$2.actionPerformed(LOTest.java:73)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
btnUpdateS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent msUpdate) {
    try {
        qstm.qDB.executeUpdate("insert into matsub (matsubid, matsubname) values 
            ('"+ txMatSID.getText() + "' + ',' + '" + txMatSName.getText() + "');");
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        MatSTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        MatSTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        getContentPane().repaint();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

I'd appreciate if there's anyone who can share the light on this problem, I myself am quite new in this java.

Comment: Related post here: [www.java-forums.org: jtable-repaint](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/46305-jtable-repaint.html)

Comment: that post is mine which is after I found out the problem I posted here about the error "java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" in which after I fixed the sql I found the repaint method isn't working as expected, now all works fine though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the literal quotes, `"`, in your relational statement, as shown in [*The Java Tutorials: Characters*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). You can use the concatenation operator, `+`, to compose your statement, as shown in [*The Java Tutorials: Strings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Comment: Thanks, yes the problem is in the quotes...sometime it's confusing on that part and make it harder to trace...was figuring out what does that error message means

Comment: The compiler saw two attributes, but more than two values. Sorry, I can't quite parse it from context alone.

Comment: it's ok...it's solved, was actually posting here cause I don't know what did that error message mean, but further trying gives me a clue on the problem...so at least I know next time that if I get the same error it means I must check my sql statement with all the quotes more carefully.

Comment: Excellent; don't forget to accept answers, as suggested in the [faq].